# Sound keep switching to DisplayPort output

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

Ubuntu 19.10

I have a soundcard on my motherboard which is what I want to use. It works fine.

But each period that the screen have been blanked and I use the PC again (and thus turn on Displayport output), the sound switches to displayport even though I have no speakers on my monitor.

Each time I have to go to settings and switch the sound output back.

Can I change the settings and make sure the settings stay on my mainboard soundcard somehow?

Comment: Thanks. I will try the solution, but need a bit time to test. I will return if it does not work.

Comment: By the way welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Okay, If it didn't work, edit the question and add note that solution didn't work. So we keep this post open.